# Can I make a NSPredicate with a condition that an attribute is not found?

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have an abstract entity with 5 sub-entities. I want to fetch 4 sub-entities. The one entity I want to exclude have an attribute "note" that other entities not include. So can I make a predicate with the condition that the attribute "note" is not found to fetch the 4 sub-entities?

I want only make a fetch request, because I use NSFetchedResultsController as data source of a table view.

Comment: Can you change the data model instead? Add a new parent for the sub-entities you want?

Comment: Are you aware of the expense and penalty imposed by using abstract entities?  Effectively all of those child entities are in a single table in the underlying SQLite database.  This results in much slower fetches and other performance issues. Do you **need** to use an abstract entity? Or would your model best be served with one entity and an attribute called `type`?

Comment: @Wain This is an app on the App Store.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I used abstract entity because it will create not many records over time, and so I can use only one request to fetch them all with NSFetchedResultsController. But I now want to add the search feature to fetch only 4 sub-entities of them.

Comment: That doesn't matter, changing the data model is still the way to go. The suggested change from @MarcusS.Zarra is the better option.

Comment: @Wain Thanks. You mean there is a way to make these 5 sub-entities convert to as 1 entity with a "type" attribute? That is good.

Comment: There is, the cost may be prohibitive for you, it depends on what the entities contain. You haven't described the entities. It would be easier to add a `type` to each sub-entity, but the benefit isn't so great.

Comment: @Wain Thanks, I will try it in the future, now it is not very urgent.